# Base-36 representation of Digest

Tags: ruby, hash, digest, base36

I would like to be able to take an arbitrary string, run it through a hashing function (like MD5), and then interpret the resulting digest in base-36.

I know there already exists a Digest library in Ruby, but as far as I can tell I can't get at the raw bytes of a digest; the `to_s` function is mapped to `hexdigest`, which is, of course, base-16.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Fixnum#to_s accepts a base as the argument. So does string#to_i. Because of this, you can convert from the base-16 string to an int, then to base 36 string:

```
i = hexstring.to_i(16)
base_36 = i.to_s(36)
```

Comment: Works great! But is it possible to extract the raw bytes of a Digest object somehow?

Comment: Nothing built in that I know of, but this question/answer shows how you can convert a Fixnum or Bignum to it's 2's complement byte array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284369/ruby-return-byte-array-containing-twos-complement-representation-of-bignum-fix

Comment: For future reference; see my answer (currently below this one) to get the raw bytes of a digest.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the raw digest bytes using [Digest::Class#digest](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/digest/rdoc/classes/Digest/Class.html#M000537):

```
Digest::SHA1.digest("test")
# => "\xA9J\x8F\xE5\xCC\xB1\x9B\xA6\x1CL\bs\xD3\x91\xE9\x87\x98/\xBB\xD3"
```

Unfortunately from that point I'm not sure how to get it into base36 without first going via another number base like in Sammy Larbi's answer..

```
bytes = Digest::SHA1.digest("test")
Digest.hexencode(bytes).to_i(16).to_s(36)
```

Hopefully you can find a better way to go from raw bytes to base36.