# Ruby unsigned right shift operator

Tags: ruby, jruby, bit-manipulation

I'm attempting to convert some of my Java code to (J)Ruby, and due to my lack of experience of bitwise operations, I ran into a problem that I can't seem to be able to solve by myself.

Simply put, I don't know how to convert this piece of Java code into Ruby, as Ruby does not appear to have the unsigned right shift operator (>>>).

```
private static short flipEndian(short signedShort) {
  int input = signedShort & 0xFFFF;
  return (short) (input << 8 | (input & 0xFF00) >>> 8);
}

def self.flip_endian(signed_short)
  input = signed_short & 0xFFFF
  input << 8 | (input & 0xFF00) >> 8
end
```

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284369/ruby-return-byte-array-containing-twos-complement-representation-of-bignum-fix

Comment: If you can work with the raw bytes instead then there is [`Array#pack`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000206).

Answer (score 0):

This will swap the first 2 bytes and cut off all the higher bits of an Integer:

```
def self.flip_endian(input)
  input << 8 & 0xFF00 | input >> 8 & 0xFF
end
```